# Android Webview - iframe content not loading, or loading incorrectly

Tags: android, html, iframe, kotlin, android-webview

I have a webview inside a recyclerview. I am loading a html string inside this webview. But some content in iFrame is not loading correctly. While the same content is loading normally iOS. Mainly PDF files that are embedded in the html content.

**ViewHolder xml** :

```
<com.novoed.ui.widgets.appWidgets.AppWebView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/richTextWebview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/loadingFrameLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Webview code** :

```
mWebView?.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true
    mWebView?.settings?.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    mWebView?.settings?.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
    mWebView?.settings?.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
    mWebView?.settings?.domStorageEnabled = true
    mWebView?.settings?.useWideViewPort = true
    mWebView?.settings?.minimumFontSize = 18
    mWebView?.settings?.setSupportZoom(!mIsVariableHeight)
    mWebView?.settings?.displayZoomControls = false
    // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
    mWebView?.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
    mWebView?.settings?.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
    /* Register a new JavaScript interface called HTMLOUT */
    mWebView?.addJavascriptInterface(MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT")
    mWebView?.settings?.builtInZoomControls = !mIsVariableHeight // allow pinch to zooom
    mWebView?.webViewClient = mWebViewClient
    mWebView?.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, webViewContent, "text/html", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString(), null)
```

This is the html content i am loading. This is fetched from API response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" /><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Novoed</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static-dev-apac.novoed.com/assets/orange/mobile_rich_text-37263494f2.css?v=1"></head><body style="ic_gradient_bg-color: transparent; background-color:transparent;"><div class="lecture-page"><div class="rich-text"><p class="froala-style-regular">This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts. This is a rich text lecture content initial texts.</p><p class="froala-style-regular">TEST edited after adding pdf</p><p class="froala-style-regular"><iframe src="https://quintet.orange.novoed.com/embeddings/114250?width=800" width="800"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"> </iframe></p><h2>Header 2</h2><h2><br></h2><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Bold text</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Italics text</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Bold and Italics text</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Underlined text</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Right aligned text</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Left aligned text</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Center aligned text</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong><br></strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Bullet text 1</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Bullet text 2</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Bullet text 3</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong><br></strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Numbered text 1</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Numbered text 2</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong>Numbered text 3</strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong><br></strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61F-Epj6A9L._SX355_.jpg" alt="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61F-Epj6A9L._SX355_.jpg" class="fr-fic fr-dii"><br></strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong><br></strong></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><strong><br></strong></p><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>R1C1</td><td>R1C2</td></tr><tr><td>R2C1</td><td>R2C2</td></tr></tbody></table><p class="froala-style-regular"><br></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><a href="https://www.google.com">Some linked text</a></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><br></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ds9SF1aYzM?vq=auto&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;origin=https://quintet.orange.novoed.com/?width=800" width="820" height="470" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock"> </iframe></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><br></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/37369607?player_id=37369607?width=800" width="820" height="470" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock"> </iframe></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><br></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><iframe src="https://quintet.orange.novoed.com/embeddings/112896?width=800" width="820" height="470" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock"> </iframe></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><br></p><p class="froala-style-regular"><iframe src="https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/44678.pdf" width="800px" height="600px"> &lt;/p&gt; </iframe></p></div></div></body></html>
```

[image: This is the first iframe.]

The pdf cannot be scrolled in the webview, and the height of that iframe is too small as well. But in iOS it works fine. In iOS the iframe is scrollable and the height is not small as well.

[image: This is the last iframe.]

This pdf is not loading in the webview. But in normal browser, the pdf is showing.

What can i do to rectify this...?

Comment: Can you please show me your xml code

Comment: @MittalVarsani I have added the xml code. Please check.